# How does gravity work?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

The math, I read, is

$$F = G\frac{m_{1}m_{2}}{r^{2}}.$$

What I'm unclear about is how does it work in practice.

Say there are two identical pebbles massing 1 kilogram each outside Sol's gravity well close enough to attract each other.

What happens then? And, How long does each 'stage' take?

Do the pebbles start to orbit around each other and eventually coalesce?

Do they, without coalescing, begin to attract other particles around them?

Comment: "How does gravity work?" "Fine, thanks!"

Comment: The explanation of Feynman starts around minute 7 (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1SrHzSGn-I8) ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you've placed your two pebbles far from any other masses the only force they will feel is their mutual gravitational attraction. Suppose you place them one metre apart, then the force they feel is given by your equation, and since in your example $m_1$, $m_2$ and $r$ are all equal to one the force each pebble will feel is just $G$ or $6.673 \times 10^{-11}$ Newtons. Each pebble will therefore start accelerating towards the other pebble at $6.673 \times 10^{-11}$ ms$^{-2}$.

Lets say you've made your pebbles from granite, which has a density of about 2700 kg/m$^3$, so the radius of the (spherical) pebbles is 0.045 m. When the pebbles collide, after a bit of bouncing around they'll settle down and remain in contact at a spacing of 0.09m. At this spacing the force between them will be about $8.2 \times 10^{-9}$ Newtons.

You could make the pebbles orbit each other. The general equations for two bodies orbiting each other are a bit complex if you're not up to speed with calculus, but if you're happy with a circular orbit it's easy to calculate the orbital velocity. For an object moving in a circular orbit the acceleration towards the centre is simply $v^2/r$. In the example above we calculated the acceleration to be $6.673 \times 10^{-11}$ ms$^{-2}$, and the radius of the orbit is half the spacing so $r = 0.5m$. That means the orbital velocity is given by:

$$ 6.673 \times 10^{-11} = \frac{v^2}{0.5} $$

so:

$$ v = 5.78 \times 10^{-6} \space \text{m/sec} $$

So if you placed the pebbles a metre apart and set each one moving at 5.78 microns per second they would follow circular orbits about their centre of mass.

If you want to know more about how two bodies orbit each other have a look at the Wikipedia article on the [two body problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-body_problem).

Comment: Just to add: The pebbles won't coalesce because the force pulling them together is very small - much smaller than the material strength. Once you get more than few 10km size lumps of rock their own gravity is strong enough to squash them into a sphere

Comment: A quick follow-up for your leisure time - Once the two pebbles are at a separation of 0.09m, do any other pebbles nearby experience two separate gravity 'field', or a single one? I would think the latter

Comment: @Everyone Why would you expect anything like that? There is nothing magic about the "1" in 1 meter. The length of the meter is entirely arbitrary. The gravitational field of extended bodies is actually the sum of the separate field from each infinitesimal bit of mass. It just happened that you can often take the results as if all the mass was at the CoM.

Comment: The second paragraph above mentioned the two pebbles settle down permanently at a distance of 0.09m. So I wondered whether neighbours then begin to experience a stronger 'pull'.

Answer (score -5):

Gravity is an effect. There is theoretical and interpreted experimental results that point to the concept that gravity is a result of neutrino refraction through matter. if this is true then the universe is comprised of a mat of neutrinos and neutrino strings in constant intertwining motion.

a good analogy of gravity is to have two hoses or sprays facing each other with a porous material like a window screen between them. the water flow are the neutrinos, the screen matter. if the flows are carefully regulated then the screen will not move. this is analogous to 'zero gravity'. now place another screen between the existing screen and a nozzle, the screens are forced together. and that is gravity.

those who say that gravity is a result of the bending of space time always show the classic parabola and geometric curve representing a gravity well caused by a planet or body. then some how the objects now represented by a ball are some how pushed into this gravity well. first what is pushing the objects down into the well. which is supposed to be gravity. well no pun intended its gravity. so they are using gravity to define gravity. secondly if objects are matter and matter creates a well would the diagram be the superposition of two of these diagrams. clearly yes and what dynamics makes that graph change? gravity back to a circular definition.

the classic panty hose bowling ball model diagram really only re states the math that newton defined 400 years ago.

it DOES NOT define a cause. where is the Force = Function (space time) ?

Comment: Gravity... is somehow caused by neutrinos?

Comment: refraction is process that only affects momentum, neutrino refraction would convey a change in momentum with out changing any of the contributors. it explains the Newtonian and relativities mass and length transforms

Comment: Much of this is copied from [this guy's other post](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/188953/what-happens-if-gravity-of-all-objects-in-the-universe-disappears/189008#189008).